# How to apply Arden's theory to determine a regular expression

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

If $P=ab$ and $Q=a^*$,
how do I use Arden's theorem to determine the regular expression $R$.
I'm not sure if I am supposed to just substitute the values of $P$ and $Q$ in the equation $R= Q + RP$. Also how would I use that to check that $R$ satisfies Arden's equation.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here. Questions should be reasonably self-contained. Could you please explain how R relates to P and Q, and perhaps even give the statement of Arden's theorem (since it's very short)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Arden's theorem states that $A^*\,B$ is the least fixed point of the equation:

$$ X = A\,X\,\cup B$$

and that $A\,B^*$ is the least fixed point of the equation:

$$X = X\,B\,\cup A$$

In your case, $R = Q\,P^* = a^* (a b)^*$.